# how to create an android layout containing tabs, and split line?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to create a layout like this for android cellphone app

[image]

I have tried to use http://www.droiddraw.org/

but didn't find the `tabs` or `split line` widges.

This is the best I managed to generate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget34"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/widget41"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:layout_x="17dp"
    android:layout_y="47dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/widget45"
    android:layout_width="58dp"
    android:layout_height="31dp"
    android:text="Search"
    android:layout_x="144dp"
    android:layout_y="64dp" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/widget46"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="place request"
    android:layout_x="212dp"
    android:layout_y="62dp" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Does someone knows a better UI Editor?

can you help adding the tabs, splitting line?

also, I want to create a gridview with fixed size (for simplicity)

how can I create one?

Comment: Don't use `AbsoluteLayout`. Never. It's deprecated since API level 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use xml for design the UI.

[Android](http://developer.android.com/design/index.html)

And look this for tabs

[tabs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)
[tabs](http://developer.android.com/design/building-blocks/tabs.html)